# Can't SELECT and ENABLE Voice Input on PC (non build in microphone)

Tags: c#, c++, dll, voice-recognition

I have a program (written on C#) which should record some speech and analyze & do something. But the problem is that I'm using desktop PC and it has not build in mic (that's why program does not records anything). I've tested it on laptop (what has build in mic) and it is working.

So can someone help me and explain how can I get plugged in mics list and choose the right one that I need and activate it (or some other decision)? I've made a research but seems like its impossible to do on C#, So i might consider C++ dev help too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should use the Asio driver in C#. 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24536/Low-Latency-Audio-using-ASIO-Drivers-in-NET

not simple but it's great for changing different input and output channels.

Comment: @TheRealLife are u sure that there is no easier way to get usb/aux input lists and "make device default" for system ?

Comment: I'm not sure maybe there is a easier way. If yes, i don't know him. I never used only one default input. So this was never my case. Sorry

Comment: Has any program captured audio from the plug-in mic, like Cortana?

Comment: @stark Skype, Battlenet desctop app and many others.

Comment: Question still actual, if someone has any answer, please leave answers ^_^

Answer (score 0):

The low-level (Win32) functions are `waveInGetNumDevs` (returns number of devices) and `waveInOpen` (identifies sources by a number from 0 to `waveInGetNumDevs()-1`).

For a nicer list, use `waveInGetDevCaps` to query the devices.